# How can I implement new functionality in Typo3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I am very new in Typo3 world and I am reading the official documentation of this CMS.

I came from Joomla and WordPress and I have some doubts about how Typo3 extends the provided functionality.

For example if, in Joomla, I would have an immage gallery or a forum into my CMS I have to install a forum component that provide me this functionality and some modules that show me some output into the pages. Similar logic is implemented by WordPress

How work Typo3? How can I add functionality to Typo3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login as an administrator and go to `Extension Manager`, next update the list of extensions from repository, and finally click the icon to download ext and install it. That's all